# what does the ! in this mean?

Tags: c#

I came across this in a code and was wondering what it was for?

thistime = !thistime;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the [logical negation unary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2.aspx) for C#.  It basically is the "opposite" of the boolean value.  If `thistime` was false previously, this will set it to true.

Comment: you can actually overload the `!` operator for custom types? I didn't expect that.

Comment: "User-defined types can overload the ! operator (see operator)." under the remarks section in the link Reed has given above